# Packing URI NUnit Test Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit

Trying to get my unit tests to work but my URI packing is failing...

I have this:

```
public static class Util
{
    public static ResourceDictionary ResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
    {
        Source = new Uri("/Engine;component/ResourceDictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    };
}
```

and in my test I'm doing this:

```
[TestFixture, Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
public class ViewModelTesting
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        string s = PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack;
    }
    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
        PackUriHelper.Create(Util.ResourceDictionary.Source);
    }
}
```

Sadly this isn't working and I'm getting an error:

```
NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
```

Not sure if anyone knows how to fix it. I'm using the NUnit framework

Answer (score 0):

Think you have to do this...

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        string s = PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack;
        var current = new Application();
    }

    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
        PackUriHelper.Create(Util.ResourceDictionary.Source);

        // have to create vm here because member vm runs before Setup....
    }
```

Seems a bit weird to have to create a new application instance but.... meh. I'm equally not sure if the `Create` bit is needed... and also it's a shame I can't have my VM as a member variable as it calls the static resource dictionary which is done before the `Setup` function is called.